# JQueryMobile - AJAX - JSON Parsing

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

Any one help me . I am using the following code for calling web service in jquery mobile. But I am getting the error " Undefined". Please point out me where I done the mistake. THanks in advance.

**Coding :**

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "http://jquery.sample.com/nodes.json",
data: ({search_keys :theName}),
dataType: 'json',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(msg) 
{
   console.log(msg);      //here, I can see the result in browser.  
   alert(msg.message);    //Undefined Error
},
error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) 
{
alert(status + errorThrown);
}
});
```

**JSON Output**
 [
   {
      "type":"Business Profiles",
      "title":"Lakeview Restaurant",
      "user":"canwest",
      "date":"1280144992",
      "node":{
         "nid":"67916",
         "type":"business_profiles",
         "language":"",
         "uid":"1",
         "status":"1",
         "created":"1278994293"
      }
   }
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an array back, not a base object - and even then there's no `message` property that I can see, so it should be:

```
alert(msg[0].title);
```

Or, loop through them all - for example:

```
$.each(msg, function(i, profile) {
  alert(profile.type);
  alert(profile.node.nid);
});
```